# Tailwind random padding in column layout

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

[image]

I'm struggling to do this well, but I want a 2-column fixed layout with fine-grained control on the width. This looks almost perfect to me, but the top-left element has some mysterious padding.

### Parent

```html
      <Layout>
        <div className="flex flex-col mt-5 w-full h-full sm:h-fit space-y-8 sm:space-y-0 sm:flex-row flex-wrap">
          <Article/>
          <Article/>
          <Article/>
          <Article/>
          <Article/>
          <Article/>
        </div>
      </Layout>
```

### Child

```html
        <div className="flex flex-col w-full h-fit sm:w-1/3 pl-5 space-y-2 m-3">

            {/* Date */}
            <span className="font-fira text-xs text-[#B3B4B4]">January 1, 2023</span>

            {/* Title */}
            <span className="font-inter font-semibold text-xl hover:opacity-50">building and automating a homelab in 2023</span>

            {/* Tags */}
            <div className="flex">
                {/* Can support multiple tags in theory, so we wrap */}
                <div className="flex space-x-1 text-xs text-[#B3B4B4] font-fira">
                    <img src="/icons/tag.svg" className="w-2" />
                    <span>life</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I realize `grid` might be better here, but I like and am more comfortable with flexbox. How can I achieve this below picture minus the odd padding/margin?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine according to [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0gRuyINfMn).

*Mysterious padding* would be because of the `padding` placed in the parent elements which you haven't produced in your question. The code you have produced is working as expected !. Check the above mentioned link